# Google chrome 6 won't work on linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I'm on Slackware 13.1, used slackbuild's sbopkg to update from Chrome 5 to Chrome 6.0.472.62. When I try to run Chrome, it starts but immediately dies. Here's the error message that comes up:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome: /usr/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/google-chrome)
/usr/bin/google-chrome: /usr/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/google-chrome)
/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
/opt/google/chrome/chrome: /usr/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /opt/google/chrome/chrome)
[5804:5823:3419253227:FATAL:chrome/browser/sync/util/user_settings.cc(39)] DROP TABLE signin_types
database disk image is malformed
--2010-10-03 11:24:40--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 72.14.253.100
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|72.14.253.100|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify clients2.google.com's certificate, issued by "/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority":
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to clients2.google.com insecurely, use '--no-check-certificate'.
Aborted
```

When I remove the Chrome 6 package and install the old Chrome 5 version, it works fine. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, it was the old Chrome ~/.config/google-chrome/Default folder. I deleted it, installed Chrome 6 again and now everything is working fine.